# Jquery-UI modal form close button display position

Tags: jquery-ui, position

I have a display problem with the close button on the top right corner on jquery ui modal form.
I had as an example: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

So I made: http://jsbin.com/atenac/3/edit

If you click Create new user you should see that the close icon is not displayed correctly.

I tested with chrome(latest) and IE9. And it is shown from the bottom right corner of the actual container.

Is there a problem with the themes, or am I missing something?
If you change to base cdn it works, but with any other css it's not working.

Code:

```
<head>
    <!-- base cdn: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
        <p class="validateTips">
            All form fields are required.</p>
        <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">
                Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <label for="email">
                Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <label for="password">
                Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <button id="create-user">
        Create new user</button>
</body>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Create an account": function () {
                    allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                    $(this).dialog("close");

                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {
                allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
            }
        });

        $("#create-user")
                  .button()
                  .click(function () {
                      $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
                  });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Should also include some of your code and not just links so that this post remains useful when the links die.

Comment: Thanks, i also added the code now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be using the incorrect stylesheet (version 1.9.0).  Linking to version 1.10.0 of the CSS seems to have fixed it:
http://jsbin.com/atenac/8/edit

The correct CSS link is:
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css